# Remove duplicates in multiple fields

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to remove duplicates of multiple fields and the retain the original one. I am a newbie in MS Access, and don't know if this kind of thing is possible.

Here is my current data

```
id  field 1 field2  field3  field4
1   mango   mango   apple   apple
2   banana  banana  banana  orange
3   grapes  mango   apple   banana
```

And this is the desired output:

```
id  field 1 field2  field3  field4
1   mango   apple       
2   banana  orange      
3   grapes  mango   apple   banana
```

Comment: What would you do in the case of `mango apple mango apple`?  Does that become `mango apple`?

Comment: yes it would become mango aple

Comment: How many fields does your table have?  Just four, or are there many?

Comment: Neither of your two tables are normalized.  You should store a single `id` - `field` relationship in a separate record.

Comment: as of now, i have 10 fields, and there's a possiblity for it to become more than 10

Comment: Than _stop now_ using Access as a spreadsheet, and read up on _How to normalize a database_. Lots of guides out there for the browsing.

Comment: hello tim and gustav, thank you so much for your advise. I know how to normalize a database. Unfortunately, the data source im recieving is like this. That's why im looking for a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UNION query can rearrange fields to records and eliminate duplicates.

```
SELECT ID, Field1 AS Data FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ID, Field2 FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ID, Field3 FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ID, Field4 FROM Table1;
```

Then that query can be source for a CROSSTAB to get similar to that desired output. The data will be alphabetically ordered on each row.

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT Query1.ID
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ID
PIVOT DCount("*","Query1","ID=" & [ID] & " AND Data<'" & [Data] & "'")+1;
```